# Why do I get this error? "ch1.c:12: error: called object ‘a - b’ is not a function"

Tags: c

I'm doing a simple challenge for a programming book that's asks to output the result of the formula f = (a − b)(x − y) using a single printf() function. and I get this Error: "error: called object ‘a - b’ is not a function"

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

 main()
 {
       int a = 5;
       int b = 1;
       int x = 10;
       int y = 5;

       printf("\nThe result of f = %d\n", (a-b)(x-y));
}
```

Comment: `main()` should be `int main(void)`.

Comment: What difference will that make, because the book im reading uses just main() as opposed to int main(void)

Comment: It would be portable and not rely on compilers implementing ancient dialects forever. The standard requires that every hosted implementation provides int main(void) and int main(int argc, char *argv[]) as entry points, others _may_ be allowed by an implementation, so those two are the only safe ones to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you trying to multiply? If so, change:

```
 printf("\nThe result of f = %d\n", (a-b)(x-y));
```

to

```
 printf("\nThe result of f = %d\n", ((a-b)*(x-y)));
```

That '*' is critical. It's the multiplication operator. The extra parens around the whole thing aren't really required, I just like to be neat by tying the whole equation up inside them.

Answer (score 6):

C/C++ doesn't allow implicit multiplication like in math. So you need to use *:

```
printf("\nThe result of f = %d\n", (a-b) * (x-y) );
                                         ^
                                   insert * here
```

As it is right now, `(a-b)` is being treated as a function call with a single parameter of `x-y`. Of course `a-b` is not a function, therefore you are getting the error that you are seeing.

Comment: @nastyn8, if an answer solves your problem, you should (in addition to voting) click on the check mark under the voting arrows.